# What does the painting of the leaflet-described elements on a map?

Tags: leaflet

I'm using Leaflet + CartoDB; I've also used Leaflet + Mapbox; and there may also be some Leaflet + GoogleMaps in my future.

My customer asked me this question: where do the Leaflet layers get painted onto the tiles? Is that done by Leaflet? Or by the Tile engine?

Does this change if I'm using a "regular" map engine (such as Mapbox) or if I'm using something like the KML-rendering plugin?

Answer (score 2):

> where do the Leaflet layers get painted onto the tiles? Is that done by Leaflet?

By default (unless you're doing something weird), that happens in your web browser, which is compositing DOM elements on top of each other. You can check this by using the developer tools in your browser and inspecting the DOM elements for the tiles, and the `<canvas>` or `<svg>` with your vector geometries. They are separate DOM elements, thus your browser is doing the compositing.

> Does this change if I'm using a "regular" map engine (such as Mapbox) or if I'm using something like the KML-rendering plugin?

Not really. Mapbox-gl-js uses insane amounts of WebGL, so that means that the brunt of the workload moves from the browser's compositor to a WebGL stack. It still happens in the web browser, albeit in a different part of the browser.

There is no "KML rendering plugin" for leaflet, just KML *loading* plugins. Vector geometries are still rendered in a `<canvas>` or `<svg>` separate from the image tiles for the basemap, then composited.

You can, of course, run your own tile server (with software such as Geoserver, Mapserver, Mapproxy, mapnik+mod_tile, tirex, tilestream, or dozens of others). In that case, you obviously know you are rasterizing your data into tiles.